# How do I render raw HTML from calling api

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor

I am working to create a blog website. The user will use a text editor to create a new blog ( which I am using is Ckeditor5). What I want is for the user can insert the images anywhere he or she wants. I successfully uploaded the post to the server when I checked the JSON, it returned something like this.

```
 {
      "id": 12,
      "title": "bài viết số 12",
      "text": "<p>`12131441411âfafafa</p><p><img src=\"null\"></p>",
      "time_created": "2024-03-03T14:34:34.090+00:00",
      "time_updated": null,
      "post_background_img": null,
      "views": null,
      "user": {
               "id": 1,
               "username": "john_doe",
               "email": "john.doe@example.com",
               "password": "$2a$12$VbU4xpQPAwrtnpPXZWB/0.J7pY6py/E04k2n5i23cL5hom.Zi85A6",
               "avatar": "http://example.com/avatar.jpg",
               "ban": false
                },
      "comments": []
    }
```

it inserts the tag into the text,
so how can I render it back to normal HTML in reactjs, I have searched on Google, and I can use `dangerous HTML,` but it is very unsafe. Is there any way I can achieve what I want, and the second thing is when I post the image to the server it returns null

this is the code snippet I used to upload

```
async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Create the blog post object
    const newBlog = {
      title,
      slug,
      text: content,
    };

    // Post the blog data to the server
    const userID = 1; // Replace with actual userID
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://englishforum.zeabur.app/api/v1/posts/user/${userID}`,
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(newBlog),
      }
    );

    if (response.ok) {
      console.log("Blog post created successfully:", newBlog);
      // You might want to redirect the user or show a success message here
    } else {
      console.error("Failed to create blog post");
      // Handle error scenario
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DOMPurify to sanitize dangerous HTML and prevent XSS attacks. DOMPurify allows you to sanitize a string full of dirty HTML, returning clean HTML. This is useful for ensuring the safety of dynamically generated content on your website. Learn more about it on [GitHub](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify).

> DOMPurify sanitizes HTML and prevents XSS attacks. You can feed DOMPurify with string full of dirty HTML and it will return a string (unless configured otherwise) with clean HTML.

```
// Assuming `response.text` contains the dirty HTML
const clean = DOMPurify.sanitize(response.text);
```

Use the `clean` variable for safe HTML content.